# Can't bind Hibernate session factory into java:app in WildFly 8.2.1

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jndi, wildfly

I am attempting to register a Hibernate Session Factory from a persistence unit in a applications deployed to WildFly 8.2.1 and I am encountering a warning exception from the Hibernate 4 code (listed below). And when I look at JNDI in the WildFly console, the session factories are definitely not registered.  I would like them to be in the "java:app" scope so that I can avoid naming collisions when more that one application might have the same session factory name.

Registering an entity manager to this scope works fine.

If I leave the "java:app" prefix off the session factory name it bind just fine into JNDI, but at a global scope.  I understand that I can impose some sort of name-spacing, but I was hoping I would not have to.

Any input would be appreciated. Thank you.

Details below...

**The persistence unit**

```
<persistence-unit name="myPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:/jdbc/MyDS</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <mapping-file>MySchema.hbm.xml</mapping-file>
    <properties>
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="java:app/em/MY_EM" />
        <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name" value="java:app/sessions/my_FACTORY"/>
        <property name="hibernate.query.imports" value="com.my.model" />
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class" value="thread" />
        <property name="hibernate.use_outer_join" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

**Exception snippet**

> 16:14:50,044 WARN  [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) - HHH000277: Could not bind factory to JNDI: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Error creating intermediate context [java:app]
>
> Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:app

**Full Warning exception from Hibernate**

> 16:14:50,044 WARN  [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) - HHH000277: Could not bind factory to JNDI: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Error creating intermediate context [java:app]
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.bind(JndiServiceImpl.java:205) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.bind(JndiServiceImpl.java:159) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry.addSessionFactory(SessionFactoryRegistry.java:103) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.(SessionFactoryImpl.java:497) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:845) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:398) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>           at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:844) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>           at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44) [jipijapa-hibernate4-3-1.0.1.Final.jar:]
>           at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
>           at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
>           at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:474) [wildfly-security-manager-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
>           at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182) [wildfly-jpa-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
>           at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
>   Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: java:app
>           at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.findContext(InitialContext.java:187) [wildfly-naming-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
>           at org.jboss.as.naming.InitialContext$DefaultInitialContext.createSubcontext(InitialContext.java:294) [wildfly-naming-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
>           at org.jboss.as.naming.NamingContext.createSubcontext(NamingContext.java:398) [wildfly-naming-8.2.1.Final.jar:8.2.1.Final]
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.createSubcontext(InitialContext.java:489) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
>           at javax.naming.InitialContext.createSubcontext(InitialContext.java:489) [rt.jar:1.8.0_51]
>           at org.hibernate.engine.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.bind(JndiServiceImpl.java:202) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
>           ... 18 more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have found the answer...

Although it is not exactly the answer I wanted. But, it makes sense.  The reason that Hibernate's JNDI binding robots cannot find the `java:app` subcontext is because, I think, it is attempting to find that name at the root and it does not exist there.  JBoss/WildFly on the other have seems to have some implicit context when deploying the application and actually as the `java:app` existing under the `applications/<module-name>` inside the JNDI tree.  Hibernate doesn't know anything about this structure.

I've modified my implementation is organize these session factory bindings by application name at the root of the JNDI tree like this:

```
hib > myApp > sessions > MY_SESSION_FACTORY
```

I hope this helps someone else out.